# Eigenvalues and index

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If I have a set of eigenvalues for a Hessian matrix of a non-degenerate critical point, and I have to determine its index, must I consider all negative eigenvalues, or must the negative eigenvalues be unique? I mean, $$(\lambda + 1)(\lambda + 2)^2 = 0 $$ is the determinant of the diagonalized Hessian of a function with three degrees of freedom. The values are $\lambda =-1, \lambda =-2, \lambda =-2$. Is the index $3$ or $2$? Alternatively, is the critical point a local maximum or a saddle point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues don't have to be unique, but you have to take into account their multiplicities, or what is nearly the same thing, the dimension of the *entire* eigenspace corresponding to each eigenvalue, to make sure you obtain/account for *every* direction in which the given function is decreasing.  Recall that a Hessian matrix at a critical point is symmetric; thus the peculiarities associated with *generalized eigenvectors* etc. do not occur in this situation; the dimension of an eigenspace is the multiplicity of its eigenvalue.   In your problem, the index is $3$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: Thank you so much. That made it clear :) May the Force be with you :)

Comment: @ Artemesia:  you know, sometimes it actually is, may I keep in tune with it more often!  Glad to help out; thanks for the kind words and the "acceptance"!

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer to your question lies in this paragraph quoted from Wikipedia.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)#Several_variables

"For a function of n variables, the number of negative eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix at a critical point is called the index of the critical point. A non-degenerate critical point is a local maximum if and only the index is n, or, equivalently, if the Hessian matrix is negative definite; it is a local minimum if the index is zero, or, equivalently, if the Hessian matrix is positive definite. For the other values of the index, a non-degenerate critical point is a saddle point, that is a point which is a maximum in some directions and a minimum in others".

Comment: I have already read that. I wanted to know whether the eigenvalues have to be unique or not. :)

Comment: My gut feeling is that it should be three. May I have the multivariable function? Then I could confirm whether this is correct or not. :)

Comment: Haha oops I don't have the function... this was a question asked by a friend a few weeks ago and I just remembered. The eigenvalues are fictitious :)

Comment: I have already received the answer, and your gut feeling was spot on :) Cheers